# IF NOT EXISTS ... INSERT INTO

Tags: mysql

I'm building an account system for my platform and I've a couple of issues with MySQL. What I want to do basically is INSERT INTO only if there isn't already a duplicate, so I tried the following query:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT email FROM accounts_list WHERE email = "chucky.modo@yahoo.com")
INSERT INTO accounts_list (email) VALUES ("chucky.modo@yahoo.com")
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work. Could you point me what I am doing wrong ? I already read some answers on StackOverflow but none help me.

Comment: Unique index on email and then catch an error if thete is a duplicate. Only safe way. Because the email could have been inserted after the check and before the insert. Or you could use transactions

Comment: Have your table a primary key?

Comment: Have you looked at the `ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE` option to `INSERT`?

Comment: I think that, as mentioned, a unique index and catching errors is preferable, because IGNORE suppresses errors. Just my two cents.

Comment: I knew about the UNIQUE thing, though I'm a little bit confused about what is the meaning of the 'SIZE' when creating a unique index ?

Answer (score 1):

Make the column email as primary key or create the unique index on it, then use this:

```
INSERT INTO accounts_list (email)
VALUES ("chucky.modo@yahoo.com")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE email = email
```